# Can't access mounted volume with python on Databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-storage-account

I am trying to give access to an Azure Storage Account Gen2 container to a team in their Databricks workspace by mounting it to a the dbfs, using Credential Passthrough. I want to be able to manage the access with the Active Directory, since eventually, there are containers to be mounted in readonly.

I based my code on this tutorial : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-passthrough#adls-aad-credentials

Extract from my conf :

```
"spark_conf": {
        "spark.databricks.cluster.profile": "serverless",
        "spark.databricks.passthrough.enabled": "true",
        "spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled": "true",
        "spark.databricks.pyspark.enableProcessIsolation": "true",
        "spark.databricks.repl.allowedLanguages": "python,sql"
    }
```

I then run the following code :

```py
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = f"wasbs://data@storage_account_name.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/data/",
  extra_configs = {
  "fs.azure.account.auth.type":"CustomAccessToken",
  "fs.azure.account.custom.token.provider.class":spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.passthrough.adls.gen2.tokenProviderClassName")
}
```

That is a success as I can access the volume with dbutils.

```py
>> dbutils.fs.ls('dbfs:/mnt/storage_account_name/data')
[FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/storage_account_name/data/folder/', name='folder/', size=0)]
```

My issue is when I run either `%sh ls /dbfs/mnt/storage_account_name/data` or try to access it with python

```py
>> import os 
>> os.listdir('/dbfs/')
Out[1]: []

>> os.listdir('/dbfs/mnt/')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs/mnt/'
```

I can't find out what I am missing. Is there something to configure to make it accessible to python ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is plain simple.

> Local file API Limitations
>
> The following list enumerates the limitations in local file API usage
>   that apply to each Databricks Runtime version.
>
> ```
> All - Does not support credential passthrough.
> ```

Source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#local-file-apis

Answer (score 3):

There are certain limitations when you are using credential passthrough option, which is why it did not work. There is no issue of syntax. See this [offical doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-passthrough#limitations) to understand.